# Use condition in update_or_create of django (DRF)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Here is my Serializer for API:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        from django.db.models import F, Case, When

        instance, created = self.Meta.model.objects.update_or_create(
            merchant=validated_data.pop('merchant'),
            defaults={
                'name': Case(
                    When(is_synchronizable=True, then='test'),
                    default=F('name')
                )
            }
        )
        return instance
```

I want to update the name just when is_synchronizable is True.
But I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'test' into field.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Field Name to `then=`. If you want to put raw value then use `Value()`

Comment: when I use Value, get this error:
AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'

Comment: Well it could be syntax problem, hard to say if you don't give me anything to work with.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this and see what will happen

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        from django.db.models import F, Case, When

        instance, created = self.Meta.model.objects.update_or_create(
            merchant=validated_data.pop('merchant'),
            defaults={
                'name': Case(
                    When(is_synchronizable=True, then=F('name')),
                    default=F('name')
                )
            }
        )
        return instance
```

you can replace F('name') with F('test') and try it as will

Comment: AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'

Comment: When I use F('test'), get the same error. django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'test' into field.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        from django.db.models import F, Case, When

        instance, created = self.Meta.model.objects.update_or_create(
            merchant=validated_data.pop('merchant'),
            defaults={
                'name': Case(
                    When(is_synchronizable=True, then=Value('test') ),
                    default=F('name')
                )
            }
        )
        return instance
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'